# Missing $ inserted in a MnotWE where all $ are matched according to editor?

Tags: math-mode, errors

The MnotWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand*{\fnn}[1]{\textrm{#1}}
\newcommand*{\gpr}[1]{\mathbin{\ast_{#1}}}
\newcommand*{\grp}[2]{\left(#1, \gpr{#1}\right)}

\begin{document}
    A group homomorphism is a map $\fnn{f}: \grp{G} \mapsto \grp{H}$ such that $x, y \in \grp{G}$...
\end{document}
```

The error:

> Missing $ inserted. ...rp{G} \mapsto \grp{H}$ such that $x, y \in

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Write

```
\newcommand*{\grp}[1]{\left(#1, \gpr{#1}\right)}
```

If you put `[2]` LaTeX thinks you have 2 *different* **mandatory** arguments.

*Edit: the following explanation is by Steven B. Segletes, credits to him.*

What this effectively means is that, as TeX is absorbing tokens for `\grp`, it sucks in an extra token that you weren't anticipating.  Just look at the output if you work your way through the errors:

```
A group homomorphism is a map $\fnn{f}: \grp{G} \mapsto \grp{H}$ 
such that $x, y \in \grp{G}$...
```

[image]

After it gets to `\grp{G}` it absorbs `\mapsto` and so you don't see that in your output.  It gets this far without an error.  Then, when it gets to `\grp{H}`, it absorbs the `$` as the 2nd argument and thus leaves you in math mode.  That is why  `such that` is presented as math.  Still no error.  But what this means is that when you get to `$x`, the `$` takes you out of math mode and so `x, y` are presented in text mode.

Then, you hit the problem, you try to typeset `\in`, now in text mode and generate the error:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.12 ...rp{G} \mapsto \grp{H}$ such that $x, y \in
                                                   \grp{G}$...
```

By forcing the compilation to continue, TeX artificially inserts the `$` here to match the required mode for `\in`.  When `\grp{G}` is reached, the `$` is again absorbed as the 2nd argument, and you are left in math mode to close out the compilation, which produces the 2nd compilation error.

Comment: ...and the closing `$` following `\grp{H}` is absorbed as the 2nd argument to `\grp`, which means you don't exit math mode until the `$` before `x`.  But then, it implies that`\in` is invoked in text mode, which is where the actual error is generated.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes It's better if you add your own answer, I'll delete mine :)

Comment: You deserve the credit.  How about I edit your answer?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Thank you to both you and CarLaTeX. :)

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes OK, I'll edit it, thank you!